# Link_to not rendering partial from custom controller action

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to render `boxes_list` by clicking `Link_to`. Don't know why its not working.

```
# Routes.rb    
resources :modifications do 
    collection do
      get 'refresh'
    end
end


# ModificationsController
  def refresh
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js {}
    end
  end


# link in /views/modifications/_boxes_list.html.erb that should refresh boxes_list
<%= link_to "refresh", refresh_modifications_path(@modification), remote: true, method: :refresh %>


# JS responce in /views/modifications/refresh.js.erb
$('#boxes_count').html("<%= escape_javascript(render( :partial => 'boxes_list' )).html_safe %>");
```

In server console I see nothing when press this link. Link is on Modifications show page under regular show action. Rails 4!

Answer (score 2):

You firstly should remove `method: :refresh` from your `link_to` (you don't need it):

```
<%= link_to "refresh", refresh_modifications_path, remote: true %>
```

You also don't need to provide an object if you're using [`collection`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-collection-routes) routes. If you used a `member` route, you'd have to pass the object.

--

To save the hassle of trying to pick through the code, here's what you should have:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :modifications do
   get :refresh, on: :member #-> url.com/modifications/:id/refresh
end

#app/controllers/modifications_controller.rb
class ModificationsController < ApplicationController
   respond_to :js, only: :refresh
   def refresh
   end
end

#app/views/modifications/refresh.js.erb
$('#boxes_count').html("<%=j render partial: 'boxes_list' %>");
```

You'd send the request as follows:

```
<%= link_to "Refresh", refresh_modification_path(@modification), remote: true %>
```

Comment: in the case of `member` route, link_to should be `refresh_modification_path(@modification)` (without s)

Comment: Now I get this: NoMethodError (undefined method `boxes' for nil:NilClass): Can't access associations in partial.

Answer (score 0):

Why you put the `method: :refresh`. Remove the `method: :refresh` from the link. Your `route` should be

```
resources :modifications do
  member do
    get :refresh
  end
end
```

Then your path should be

```
<%= link_to "refresh", refresh_modification_path(@modification), remote: true %>
```

And in `refresh' action

```
def referesh
  @modification = Modification.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
     format.js{}
  end
end
```

Source [Adding More RESTful Actions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.0/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions)

Comment: I tried, but now I have this: `Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 3ms
ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat): app/controllers/modifications_controller.rb:18:in 'refresh'`

Comment: Can you please comment all from `/views/modifications/refresh.js.erb` file and write `alert(Hello)`. This will test your code it goes to `refresh` with `ajax' call. Let me know

Comment: tried, but same problem with unknown format. Alert not cumming up!

Comment: As you declared `refresh` as a `collection`. Is it ok?? If yes, so why are you passing @modification to them? If you need a route with a `@modification` then change `collection` to `member`.

Comment: Should I correct my routes? what would be more preferable?

Comment: now I get `NoMethodError (undefined method 'boxes' for nil:NilClass)` Any ideas?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98816/discussion-between-nitin-srivastava-and-danielsv).